# Fixed Width Glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am working on a web site that uses Bootstrap. I am only using the included Glyphicons pack. There are three important features from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) that I need though.

1. Fixed Width Icons
2. Fa-Spin
3. The rotated and flipped options

These three features can be seen in the [examples](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/). My question is, is there a way to include these features with the Glyphicons pack? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely, it's just css. You can inspect the desired options (I recommend chrome dev tools) see the css. Might not be able to find the keyframes for spin, but you could download the css for FA and just search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajmajmajma is correct. Those effects are simply css additions to FontAwesome and can be easily replicated. You can also copy those css rules, add them to your own stylesheet, and then add the corresponding classes to the glyphicon.

Here is an example and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3su5sem/1/):

```
.glyphicon-fw {
    width: 1.28571429em;
    text-align: center;
}

.glyphicon-spin {
    -webkit-animation: glyphicon-spin 2s infinite linear;
    animation: glyphicon-spin 2s infinite linear;
}

.glyphicon-rotate-90 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.glyphicon-rotate-180 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.glyphicon-rotate-270 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.glyphicon-flip-horizontal {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0, mirror=1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
.glyphicon-flip-vertical {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
:root .glyphicon-rotate-90,
:root .glyphicon-rotate-180,
:root .glyphicon-rotate-270,
:root .glyphicon-flip-horizontal,
:root .glyphicon-flip-vertical {
  filter: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glyphicon-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes glyphicon-spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: great answer, Makes the point and makes the solution easy to find. I use both fa and glyphicons on a site, and even though fa is included, the fa styles don't always work on glyphicons unless explicitly declared like this. Haven't had time to figure out why, I just add this to my document and it works fine. - Solution.